# Запись данных из get запроса в txt файл

Tags: php, html, post, запрос, get

Ребят, нужна помощь с сохранением данных из GET запроса. Txt файл создается не после нажатия кнопки submit, а просто при открытии самой формы, в следствии чего он пустой. Не совсем понимаю, как реализовать запуск php скрипта, после нажатия кнопки.

```
<?php
    $date = date_create();
    $file_name = "log/" . date_format($date, 'YmdHis.u') . ".txt";
    $f = fopen($file_name, "a+");
    fwrite($f, $_POST["us_name"] ."\n".$_POST['em']."\n" ."\n".$_POST['us_url']."\n");  
    fclose($f);
?>

<form accept-charset="windows-1251" method="get" action="http://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='m' value='<?php echo $merchant_id;?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='oa' value='<?php echo $order_amount;?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='o' value='<?php echo $order_id;?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='s' value='<?php echo $sign;?>'>
        <input type="text" name="us_name" placeholder="Имя" required>
        <input type="text" name="em"  placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="text" name="us_url" placeholder="Ссылка" required>
        <button type="submit" class="butsub">Заказать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Как это сочетается? `method="get"` и `$_POST["us_name"] ... $_POST['em'] ...` http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Ну обычно это делается проверкой введенных данных или нажатой кнопки `submit` с ее `name`. А вообще правильно подметили. что `$_POST` не в вашем случае, вам нужно `$_GET`

Comment: Добавил для кнопки name, и изменил скрипт, но теперь даже не создается пустой файл.
    <button type="submit" name="log">Заказать</button>
    <?php
if ($_GET['log']) {
    $date = date_create();
    $file_name = "title/" . date_format($date, 'YmdHis.u') . ".txt";
    $f = fopen($file_name, "a+");
    fwrite($f, $_GET['us_name'] ."\n".$_GET['em'] ."\n" ."\n".$_GET['us_url'] ."\n");  
    fclose($f);
    ?>

Comment: @RomanRomanov, button, да и input submit не отправляют своих значений с формой (input как минимум через get-запрос). Проверку нужно делать на значения во всех обязательных полях формы: `if (isset($_GET['m']) && isset($_GET['oa']) && isset($_GET['o']) && и так далее)`.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно весь код написать в обработчик формы. Адрес к обработчику поместить в атрибут action формы. 
В обработчике получаем данные из глобального массива $_GET.  Далее, создаем файл. Записываем в него данные. И делаем редирект на страницу формы, например.

Answer (score 1):

При get запросе данные будут доступны в переменной `$_GET`, не `$_POST`

```
fwrite($f, $_GET["us_name"]."\n".$_GET['em']."\n"."\n".$_GET['us_url'] ."\n");
```